# Phonebook with multiple numbers (PHP-PDO)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I need to create a phone book with multiple phone numbers using PHP and MySQL.

This is the phones table:

```
+----+---------+--------+
| ID | user_id | number |
+----+---------+--------+
|  1 |    1    | 111111 |
|  2 |    1    | 222222 |
|  3 |    1    | 333333 |
|  4 |    2    | 111111 |
+----+---------+--------+
```

And this is my code:

```
<?php
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=phonebook", "root", "");

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
        $newPhones = $_POST['phones'];

        foreach ($newPhones as $i => $newPhone) {
            //If the user modify a saved number, UPDATE.
            //else INSERT.
        }
    }

    $resp = $conn->query("SELECT number FROM `phones` WHERE `user_id`=1");
    while ($phone = $resp->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) $phones[] = $phone['number'];
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <hr>
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <div class="phones">
                <?php if (!isset($phones)) $phones[] = ''; ?>
                <?php foreach ($phones as $i => $phone): ?>
                    <div class="phone">
                        <input type="text" name="phones[]" value="<?=$phone?>" /><a href="#" class="remove" style="<?php if ($i==0) echo "display:none;"; ?>">Remove</a>
                    </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
            <a id="add" href="#">New</a>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#add').on('click',function(e){$('.phones').after($('.phones .phone:first').clone(true,true).children('.remove').show().end().find("input:text").val("").end());e.preventDefault();});
    $('.remove').on('click',function(e){$(this).parent().remove();e.preventDefault();});
</script>
```

My problem is when the user modifies or adds a phone numbers, how can i insert the new phone numbers entered by the user or update the phone numbers changed by the user in the HTML form?

**Edit #1:**
I added a column to my table called "position" and I'm trying to use the position number of phone in the `POST` array to identify it.

This is my new table:

```
+----+---------+--------+----------+
| ID | user_id | number | position |
+----+---------+--------+----------+
|  1 |    1    | 111111 |    0     |
|  2 |    1    | 222222 |    1     |
|  3 |    1    | 333333 |    2     |
|  4 |    2    | 111111 |    0     |
+----+---------+--------+----------+
```

And this my new PHP submit code:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    $newPhones = $_POST['phones'];

    foreach ($newPhones as $i => $newPhone) {
        $resp = $conn->query("UPDATE `phones` SET `number`={$newPhone} WHERE `user_id`=1 AND `position`={$i} LIMIT 1");
    }
}
```

But now, the problem is, `UPDATE` only work if the row exist, but if not exist, how can i insert it?

I tried using the value returned by `PDO::rowCount` function (if it returns 0, insert it). But if the value is not modified, `PDO::rowCount` also return 0.

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: just make sure when you're making (or the user) an edit, just use the ID of that row so that you can use it in your UPDATE statement, and for the insert, as usual, just use an INSERT statement

Comment: yes, but how can i know what rows are modified and what rows are new to `UPDATE` or `INSERT`? (i cant use `ON DUPLICATE KEY` because there are no unique columns)

Comment: You could use the row `ID` as the array key, so when you post your form, you will have the row `ID` to `UPDATE`. This will require to slightly change your  javascript code for `#add`, as you would need to create an array key(s) that you could check for in php to do the `INSERT`

Comment: different user has same phone number=> how it is possible? As per your example, 2 diff user has same no(111111)...

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is as follows (however this works on the basis that you know the User ID - your question has a hard coded UserID):

1. Start a transaction
2. Delete all your positions and users
3. Insert all the new positions

That way you won't need to worry about updating or keys - you simply reset that chunk of user data.

Note that the transaction is important - you don't want to find you delete your entries and then your code fail and you lose what you had.

I hope that helps.